# UE4 - Application won’t run on Android tablet

Tags: android, tablet, unreal-engine4

So, I did a video-game in UE 4.8 and compiled it for Android.
   It’s a game for training mathematical abilities in first and second
   graders, using Android tablets. However, the game won’t run in the
   tablets we are using for the training program. After installing the
   APK, when I try to run the game, it immediately closes and a sign
   appears saying: “The application has stopped”.  I installed the
   application in other several android devices and it works fine (e.g.
   LG F60, Samsung Galaxy S5). However, I need to make it work for this
   particular tablet, because those are the ones we are using for the
   training program and we have like 80 of them. The tablet is a
   ProntoTec X1, these are the specs:

- CPU: All winner A31s Quad Core-Cortex A7, 1.2GHZ;
- OS: 4.4 KitKat;
- RAM: 1G DDR3;
- 10.1-inch screen, 1024 x 600 Pixels

I’ve tried different things, like compiling an empty project, but is the same: it works on other devices, but not on these tablets. I also compiled the game using different API versions of the SDK and NDK, but that didn’t help either. These are the versions that I’m currently using: ndk-r10e, ant-1.9.6, jdk-1.7.0, sdk platform-19 (android studio 1.2.2). 
Please, any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: You nee to look at crash logs or something. Can you get a logcat?

Comment: I've look at the log from the application (the one that the app itself creates), and it's empty. It only says that the game started at X time, and that's it. I guess I could debug the app using Android Studio, and create a bug report... I'm not sure how to use logcat...

Comment: Learning opportunity? Open an adb shell and type `logcat`, assuming you have such access.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the droid versions supported, also have a look at the droid permissions, I had this issue some time ago and the permissions is what did it for me.